# Our website does not create "SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE" cookie

Tags: experience-analytics

Our website does not create `"SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE`" cookie

I have looked into showconfig and can see

```
<processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EnsureSessionContext.EnsureDevice, Sitecore.Analytics"/>
```

We have the VisitorIdentification tag in our layout and Tracking is enabled.

I can see the anonymous contacts and intercations created in the mongo db and Reporting database. It's just that we don't have cookie and all of them are recording as a separate entry in the database even if the request is coming from the same device and same browser

I turned below setting to true and I can see all the anonymous contacts listed in the ExperienceProfile

```
 <setting name="ContentSearch.Analytics.IndexAnonymousContacts" value="true"/>
```

Can someone please suggest what else could be the reason?

We are using Sitecore 8.2 update 4. I can also see the cookie is present on my dev site. Thanks

Comment: Do you have VisitorIdentification in your layout file?

Comment: Or any customization that disables Tracker?

Comment: @MarekMusielak yes we do have the VisitorIdentification  in the layout

Comment: @Joost Tracking is also enabled

Comment: Could it be that cookie is created for wrong domain?

Comment: @Joost  On our website URL, I did check in developer tools -> Application -> cookies and all the domains there but couldn't find it.

Comment: Also please check there will be no javascript error. First please try accessing the Experience Analytics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the below setting pointing to the wrong domain

```
<setting name="Analytics.CookieDomain" value="****" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds silly, but is Tracking enabled in the config?

Ensure that the Sitecore setting:

```
Xdb.Tracking.Enabled
```

is set to true.

And Ensure that layouts contain the VisitorIdentification tag or MVC helper

Comment: We do have the VisitorIdentification tag and Tracking enabled.